# Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00007FFBEEEB2F40A (ucrtbased.dll) : 0xC0000005; нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу

Tags: c++, рекурсия

При выводе следующей программы (код см. ниже)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <semaphore>

using namespace std;

// объявляем функцию для вычисления границы, которая будет разделять два массива
int bound_div (int iteration, int n) {
    // создаем массив , куда будем записывать данные
    int bound_array [3];
    // находим новые элементы массива
    // рекурсивная функция здесь
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            if (n % 2 == 0) {
                bound_array[i] = n / 2;
            }
            else {
                bound_array[i] = n / 2 + 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (n % 2 == 0) {
                bound_array[i] = bound_array[i - 1] / 2;
            }
            else {
                bound_array[i] = bound_array[i - 1] / 2 + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    // запишем значение границы
    int bound = bound_array[iteration];
    return bound;
}

// функция для нахождения среза массива

double* array_slice(double* array, int a, int b) {
    double* slice = new double[b - a];
    for (int i = a; i < b; i++) {
        slice[a-i] = array[i];
    }
    return slice;
}

// функция для вычисления суммы элементов, обратных элементам массива
double bar(double sum, double* squares, int b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        sum += 1 / squares[i];
        std::cout << "Sum is " << sum << "\n";
    }
    return sum;
}

// сделаем функцию, которая будет выполняться потоком
void united_function (double sum, double* squares, int a, int b) {
    bar(sum, array_slice(squares, a, b), b);
}

int main()
{
    // запрашиваем переменную
    int n;
    // запросим у пользователя количество элементов массива
    cout << "Sum 1/ArEls\nThe program finds the sum of elements inversing array elements\nEnter the number of array elements:\n";
    cin >> n;
    
    // создаем массив
    double* squares = new double[n];
    // инициализируем массив
    for (int i = 1; i < n + 1; i++) {
        squares[i - 1] = i * i;
    }

    // создаем счетчик для суммы в последовательном варианте
    double sum_seq = 0;

    // создаем счетчики для суммы в параллельном варианте
    cout << "Parallel variant\n";
    double sum_par_1 = 0;
    double sum_par_2 = 0;

    // создаем счетчик для итерации
    int iteration = 0;

    // передаем сумму потокам
    if (n > 100) {
        // сделаем новую переменную
        int bound = bound_div(iteration, n);
        // поток
        std::thread thread(united_function, sum_par_1, squares, 0, bound);
        thread.detach();
        // функция в главном потоке
        united_function(sum_par_2, squares, bound, n);
        // считаем общую сумму
        double sum_par = sum_par_1 + sum_par_2;
        // выводим ее на экран
        cout << "The general sum is " << sum_par << endl;
    }
    else {
        double sum_par = 0;
        bar(sum_par, squares, n);
        // выводим ее на экран
        cout << "The general sum is " << sum_par << endl;
    } 

    // записываем последовательный вариант
    cout << "Sequential variant\n";
    bar(sum_seq, squares, n);
    cout << "\n";
    // выводим результат на экран
    cout << "The general sum is " << sum_seq << endl;
}
```

появляется следующая ошибка:
Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00007FFCB014E210 (ntdll.dll) в Lab_1_final_version_new_2.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.
Скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Действительно ли эта ошибка связана с рекурсивной функцией? И как ее исправить?

Comment: Как минимум, 1. поток надо не `detach()`, а `join()` после расчета в основном потоке, иначе нет гарантии, что он успеет завершиться. Передавать `sum` по значению и надеяться что-то получить — наивно :), нужно передавать по ссылке. Это так, первые впечатления...